# Using $ in a string in a dataweave expression

Tags: graphql, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm writting an GraphQL query and i have to use $like but i get a Syntax Error: Unexpected  from the GraphQl service how can i use $like like a string without having this error ?

i try this :

```
'funquery(filter:"{\"++ vars.filter++\":{\"$like\":\"++ vars.value ++\"}}") {
#values to get
}'
```

but this get me an error from the dataweave : Unable to resolve reference of: 'like'.
So i try this :

```
'funquery(filter:"{\"++ vars.filter++\":{\"\$like\":\"++ vars.value ++\"}}") {
#values to get
}'
```

and with this i got Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>

Comment: The question misses details. What is the input, what is the expected output? How to reproduce the issue? Are the apostrophes part of the expression? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also provide the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) and details. The second error can not be reproduced. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are trying to output a GraphQL query that replaces the values of the variable and leaves them between quotes. If that is the case the quotes are incorrectly balanced in your script. Also GraphQL is not JSON, so using JSON as the output format may break quoting. Try using application/java to return a string with the query:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var varFilter="abc"
var varValue="def"
---
"funquery(filter:{\"" ++ varFilter ++ "\":{\"\$like\":\"" ++ varValue ++ "\"}}) {
#values to get
}"
```

The output is a string:

```
funquery(filter:{"abc":{"$like":"def"}}) {
#values to get
}
```